# Firebase Database Runloop 3.0.0 - Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app for production in my Crashlytics data, this crash is on top.
below is the crash log for the same

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzy.run (Unknown Source)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)

    Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
    java.util.NoSuchElementException

    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegx.zze (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefh.zzb (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefh.zzh (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzedn.zze (Unknown Source)
    com.google.firebase.database.zzq.run (Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:428)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)

    Caused by java.util.NoSuchElementException

    java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next (AbstractList.java:364)
    java.util.AbstractList.equals (AbstractList.java:521)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zzc (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeil.zza (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefg.zza (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefl.call (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegx.zze (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefh.zzb (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzefh.zzh (Unknown Source)
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzedn.zze (Unknown Source)
    com.google.firebase.database.zzq.run (Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:428)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

When I did research for this crash on StackOverflow and on firebase GitHub repo, I came across following reasons because of which users were getting this crash earlier.
 1. Using startAt() or endAt() queries.
 2. Using transactions
3. Using multi-process app
4. Setting persistence enabled in application class.

[This](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/45) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724801/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0) are some of the links which I have checked.

But my app is not using any query which is using startAt() or endAt(), it is also not using any transaction and I have also make sure that persistence is not set in application class for any database.

But still I am getting this crash and I am unable to solve it because it is not giving me origin in my code (from where it is getting crashed) so that I can reproduce it.

Current firebase version in my gradle is 11.8.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542493/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0-workaround-for-strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001906/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0-in-my-production-android-app-ple

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208878/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0-related-to-persistence-and-querie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382830/uncaught-exception-in-firebase-runloop-3-0-0-please-report-to-supportfirebas

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Fatal+Exception:+java.lang.RuntimeException+Uncaught+exception+in+Firebase+Database+runloop+(3.0.0)+site:stackoverflow.com&client=ubuntu&hs=xzx&channel=fs&dcr=0&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiulL6N5IHaAhUL3Y8KHQczC7QQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1598&bih=726

Comment: I have already checked all the above links, and error mentioned in above questions is hardAssert failed, but i am not getting that error.